PDE describing relaxation to a given constraint
In physics, the relation between different thermodynamic potentials, say $f$ and $p$, is of the kind
$$
f(x) = x f'(x) - p(x)
$$
where $x$ is a thermodynamic variable. This is for motivating where the question comes from. In practice, we only need the relation between the real-valued functions $f$ and $p$ and the real variable $x$ given in the above equation.
Now, assume that we obtained an approximation to $f$ and $p$, say $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{p}$. However, despite $\tilde{f}(x)\approx f(x)$ and $\tilde{p}(x)\approx p(x)$ to a high level of precision in the whole domain, it is not guaranteed that
$$
\tilde{f}(x) \approx x \tilde{f}'(x)  - \tilde{p}(x)
$$
to the same level of precision.
Informal statement of the problem: I would like to "slightly modify" $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{p}$ to new functions ${\bar{f}}\approx \tilde{f}$ and $\bar{p}\approx \tilde{p}$ such that the constraint $\bar{f}(x) \approx x \bar{f}'(x)  - \bar{p}(x)$ is respected.
Question: I am wondering if there are known systems of PDEs that allow you to "relax" $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{p}$ such that, at the end of the "time evolution", the relation above is respected:

We may consider two functions $f(x,t)$ and $p(x,t)$ and set up a Cauchy problem with initial condition $f(x,0)=\tilde{f}(x)$ and $p(x,0)=\tilde{p}(x)$.

Evolve the system of PDEs such that, asymptotically, ${f}(x,t) = x \partial_x{f}'(x,t)  - {p}(t,x)$ for $t \rightarrow \infty$.

Of course, the relaxed functions shall stay "close" to the initial ones (i.e. it's easy to write down some PDEs that relax everything to exactly zero!).


Note: I am aware that this problem is rather vague from the point of view of technical details, but I am mostly looking for hints and ideas, as well as possible approaches to this kind of problem (or similar ones), namely: we have good approximations to the exact solution that, however, do not respect a fundamental constraint and we have to "minimally correct them" such that the constraint is satisfied. Partial answers and links to possible approaches are welcome.

Given $\tilde{f}$, why don't you define $\tilde{p}$ as $\tilde{p}(x)=x\tilde{f}'(x)-\tilde{f}(x)$? Or, given $\tilde{p}$, why don't you define $\tilde{f}$ as the solution to the differential equation $x\tilde{f}'(x)-\tilde{f}(x)=\tilde{p}(x)$?

@Gonçalo good question! Such an approach would give a worse approximation to the exact $f$ and $p$. If both $\tilde{f} \approx f $ and $\tilde{p} \approx p $, changing one of the two (say $\tilde{p}$) to $\tilde{\tilde{p}} = x \tilde{f}'-\tilde{f}$ is almost always guaranteed to result in a horrible approximation $\tilde{\tilde{p}}$ of $p$.

I am checking this beautiful work: "Constrained Differential Optimization" by  John Platt, Alan Barr (1987) to get inspiration for a possible approach. I think it may of interest also for other users: they derive constrained optimization based on modifying gradient descent to incorporate Lagrange multipliers (the dynamical equations update the Lagrange multiplier to enforce constraints). I will update the question if I get anything interesting.
